# AppendTo same div multiple times with slice() and clone()

Tags: jquery, append

I'm having trouble with the code 'appendTo' to move the same div more than once. What I'm trying to do is append a list of divs in `#oldsection` to `#newsection`, two at a time in subclass `.movehere`

I'm moving divs two at a time using `.slice(0,2). For some reason, using`.slice`and`.clone` doesn't work well together. Perhaps this is not the right solution? I'd like for the code to look like this:

```html
<div id="newsection">
   <h3> ALL </h3>
   <div id="all">
      <div class="movehere">
         <div class="blue all">A</div>
         <div class="red all">B</div>
      </div>
      <div class="movehere">
         <div class="blue all">C</div>
         <div class="blue all">D</div>
      </div>
      <div class="movehere">
         <div class="red all">E</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <h3> RED </h3>
   <div id="red">
      <div class="movehere">
          <div class="red all">B</div>
          <div class="red all">E</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <h3> BLUE </h3>
   <div id="blue">
      <div class="movehere">
         <div class="blue all">A</div>
         <div class="blue all">C</div>
      </div>
      <div class="movehere">
         <div class="blue all">D</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="oldsection"></div>
```

The code to appendTo 'colored section' `#blue,#red` and 'all sections' `#all` is working but doesn't work when they're there together. 
For some odd reason, only the red divs are showing in the ALL section but when the code under `//append colored section` and `.clone()` is removed, the red and blue divs come back and works just fine.

Here is my current code: Please look at the comments that say //THIS CODE. Those are the two codes that I can't get to work at the same time.

```html
<div id="newsection">
   <h3> ALL </h3>
   <div id="all">
      <div class="movehere"></div>
      <div class="movehere"></div>
      <div class="movehere"></div>
   </div>
   <h3> RED </h3>
   <div id="red">
      <div class="movehere"></div>
   </div>
   <h3> BLUE </h3>
   <div id="blue">
      <div class="movehere"></div>
      <div class="movehere"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="oldsection">
   <div class="blue all">A</div>
   <div class="red all">B</div>
   <div class="blue all">C</div>
   <div class="blue all">D</div>
   <div class="red all">E</div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $all = $('#all');
   $('#oldsection div').each(function () {

   //append colored sections
      var classColor = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
      var $moveClass = $('#newsection #' + classColor + " .movehere");
      $moveClass.each(function () {
         $('#oldsection .' + classColor).slice(0,2).appendTo($(this));
       })

   //append ALL sections
       $("#newsection #all .movehere").each(function() {
         var $div = $("#oldsection div");
         $(this).append($div.clone().slice(0,2));
      })
   })
 });
```

```css
.blue { background-color: #76BAE4; }
.red {background-color: #F45E60; }
.movehere { margin: 5px auto;}
```

---

I had some help in another form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58087168/519413.

Comment: Classes should never be used to store logic-sensitive data. `$(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0]` will fail as soon you decide to add (prepend) a cool style class to those elements. Use a specific `data-*` attribute like `data-color="blue"` and read it using `$(this).data('color');`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I'll keep that in mind for the future. I added a data-color attribute to all the `#oldsection div` and changed the variable to `var classColor = $(this).data('color');` but this function still does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

- Since (strangely) you already have your empty `.movehere` placeholders, simply target them
- Target the old divs in groups by *all* and *colors*
- (Use `.filter()` to filter the all into specific color groups by class-name)
- Use  i.e: `$allDIV.slice(gB*i, gB*i+gB).clone()`, with the *GroupBy* `gB` variable being set to `2`

Use the `.append(function(index, element))` method callback.

To explain the code `$allMH.append(i => $allDIV.slice(gB*i, gB*i+gB).clone() );`, 
Say you have 3 `#all>.movehere` elements, the above will iterate three times looking like (in each iteration):

> ```
> (i=0): $allDIV.slice(0, 2).clone() // appended to the currently iterated DIV  
> (i=1): $allDIV.slice(2, 4).clone() // appended to the currently iterated DIV  
> (i=2): $allDIV.slice(4, 6).clone() // appended to the currently iterated DIV
> ```

Thanks to the implicit return of arrow function `=>` the *sliced* groups are appended to the currently iterating element - directly.

#### Example:

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

   const $allMH  = $('#all  > .movehere'),
         $redMH  = $('#red  > .movehere'),
         $bluMH  = $('#blue > .movehere'),
         $allDIV = $('#oldsection > div'),
         $redDIV = $allDIV.filter('.red'),
         $bluDIV = $allDIV.filter('.blue'),
         gB = 2; // Group by

   $allMH.append(i => $allDIV.slice(gB*i, gB*i+gB).clone() );
   $redMH.append(i => $redDIV.slice(gB*i, gB*i+gB).clone() );
   $bluMH.append(i => $bluDIV.slice(gB*i, gB*i+gB).clone() );

   $('#oldsection').empty();

 });
```

```css
.blue { background-color: #76BAE4; }
.red {background-color: #F45E60; }
.movehere { margin: 15px auto;}
```

```html
<div id="newsection">
   <h3> ALL </h3>
   <div id="all">
      <div class="movehere"></div>
      <div class="movehere"></div>
      <div class="movehere"></div>
   </div>
   <h3> RED </h3>
   <div id="red">
      <div class="movehere"></div>
   </div>
   <h3> BLUE </h3>
   <div id="blue">
      <div class="movehere"></div>
      <div class="movehere"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<h3> OLD SECTION </h3>
<div id="oldsection">
   <div class="blue all">A</div>
   <div class="red all">B</div>
   <div class="blue all">C</div>
   <div class="blue all">D</div>
   <div class="red all">E</div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

If afterwards you want to empty your old container you can use

```
$('#oldsection').empty();
```